# Select an element that has an sibling with specific child using purely CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Say you have:

```
----------
    X
----------
    Y -> Z
----------
```

Given Z is children of Y, i want to select all X which have a sibling that has a child Z

Comment: Please edit - you seem to have the wrong variable letters in the description or code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** select a parent element in CSS based upon the child and sibling elements...so there's no way you can get this done...

So there's no CSS parent selector yet..

[CSS 2 Selector's Specification Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)

[CSS 3 Selector's Specification Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

In CSS4 Specification I remember there was something like `$` kind of thing but it was rejected later

Answer (score 1):

There is currently [no way](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) to select the parent of an element in CSS That is why it is impossible to select sibling that has a child Z.